# Dynamically adding and removing javascript/css with Jquery (or other library)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-routing

I am trying to compare having a 1 page app with clientside routing to having a asp mvc app which just routes to html files, to see which is more appropriate for my current project. As I have no need for any Asp Mvc features its all javascript/html which communicates with a web service.

However one problem I can forsee with the one page app is that my site isnt really 1 page, so I would be having to have on main index.html which contained all shared resources. Then dynamically load in new pages based on the hashbang and add in any required scripts and css. This doesn't seem to hard as Jquery I believe provides a .load() method or something similar to get external resources... my problem though is getting rid of them once I am done...

Is there any way to do this, so you target ONLY certain script/link tags, can you give them Ids or something?

Any help on this would be great...

== EDIT ==

Added a simple example to show what I mean:

```
<!-- Script already in page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
<!-- Dynamically added script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 // some javascript
</script>
```

How can you tell which ones you should remove? If you could apply an id or uniqueness to each script then it may be ok, but thats what i am getting at with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shre i understand why you would like to do that but `link` element (for css) and `script` (for js) are elements like any other and they can be deleted with `remove()`.

Comment: yes but that doesn't mean that aren't loaded into memeory/cache

Comment: I belive what browser puts in cache/memory is out of your control.

Comment: I am more worried about how you know *WHICH* link/script tags to delete... as if you start adding some dynamically then they are just going to look like all other tags, just with a different src/href

Comment: you can assign them id's, like any other elements. Also, with jquery you can target them by attribute's (src/rel) value.

Comment: Thanks Litek thats all im after, you win the answer!

Answer (score 1):

There are zero benefits to "removing resources."  When a script has been loaded, removing the script tag from the page later has no purpose--it won't improve your browser performance at all, nor will it harm it to keep the files around.

Simply add your resources as needed and write your code such that it won't execute erroneously.

Comment: You raise a good point, which I didnt think about... this is why using asp mvc for my routing and just redirect to html pages was a good option, as I need to reset the page every time a new inner page is loaded. Doing it via ajax wont reset anything, so if I have event listeners or jquery effects in play they will persist as you mentioned... I have different css files for each sub-page and some of them would cause crazy behaviour if loaded together... looks like its server side postbacks then :(

Comment: If your code is already written, then yes, it'll be tough to do what you want.  I believe you CAN unload CSS, that's a different ballgame.  As for the listeners, you'd have to unbind conflicting ones.  So in scriptA, when you're binding, you first do an unbind then bind.  Then in scriptB you do the same.  When scriptB is loaded, it would unbind conflicting events in scriptA.  `$('#elem').unbind('click').click(...)`

Comment: Yeah seems like at the moment using the server side for routing is my best option. I just wanted to be purely clientside if possible, but the amount of hoops to jump through would be a pain, and i would be search engine unfriendly off the bat... thanks for your advice... I would mark the post up but this is just an unregistered account :(

Comment: You could switch the answer. :)  But really, I don't like AJAX pages like that if they don't degrade well.  I'm of the camp that JavaScript shouldn't be required to load your page (GASP!).  It's a candy coating--without it your site should be completely functional (and delicious).